# Pass argument from bash to C

Tags: c, bash, unix, arguments

How can I pass arguments from a bash command to a program in c?

For example, if I have a command that looks something like this:

```
./c_program argument
```

How can I access that argument in the C program itself?
Can I just use the variables such as $1, like you can in bash?

Comment: See `main(), argv, argc` - should be in the first few pages of any `C` book - also, could probably be determined from an internet search using your problem title

Answer (score 1):

Try out the following code and see how it behaves with different numbers of arguments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    for (int i=0; i<argc; i++) {
        printf("%s\n",argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As *Stephan Lechner* stated in his code, you use the variables `argc` and `argv`. First of all you must have `int main(int argc, char **argv) {` in your code to get those variables. `char **argv` can be different though, i.e. `char *argv[]` works and so does `const char *argv[]`

`char **argv` is essentially an array of `strings`, but this kind of string is better known as a `char array` (short for 'character array'). You'll want to use it somewhat like this:

```
int option1 = 0;
for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
  if(strcmp(argv[i], "--the-input-you-were-expecting-here") == 0)
    option1 = 1;
}
```

Note: argv includes the *./c_program* part of your command as the first index, in result of this `argv[0]` will equal `"./c_program"` if your command was `"./c_program --the-input-you-were-expecting-here"`.